# How to Split a row into multiple based on a column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have to split a row into multiple rows based on a count column. if count is 6 , row should split into 2, first row's count will be 5 and next will be 1. If count is 17, there will be 4 split, 3 rows with 5 each and last count will be 2.

Table will have 2 columns :

```
    id    CNT
  ------------
    10    17
```

Above row should split into 4 like below:

```
    id    CNT
--------------------
    10    5
    10    5
    10    5
    10    2
```

I have tried using mod and division to find the total number of split but could not find final solution.

Please provide your input to achieve this.

Comment: so basically you want to divide your number in numbers of `5` and `2`. what if there is `18`...?

Comment: If CNT is 18,  split will be 4 times, 3 rows with CNT as 5 and 4th row will be with CNT as 3. Each row should contain max(cnt) as 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this. I am not sure about the syntax used in `teradata`, but this will surely give you idea about how you can sort out your problem.

First we need to find the quotient and remainder portion of each number with respect to the id. Then quotient is the number of times you want to repeat your loop, for which we are using `recursive cte` and remainder is the last row need to be added to get the sum of numbers equal to your value.

Sample query will be like this.

```
declare @tab table ( id int, num int )
insert into @tab ( id, num )
values ( 1, 17 )
, ( 2, 22 )

; with cte as (
select id, num , num %5 as remainder, num/5 as quo from @tab )
, ct (sl, id, num, val) as (
select 1 as sl, id, num, 5 as val from cte
union all
select c.sl+1, t.id, t.num, c.val from cte as t inner join ct as c on t.id=c.id where c.sl<t.quo
)
, cfinal (id, num, val) as (
select id, num, val from ct 
union all
select id, num, remainder from cte
)
select * from cfinal order by id, val desc
```

Result

```
id          num         val
----------- ----------- -----------
1           17          5
1           17          5
1           17          5
1           17          2
2           22          5
2           22          5
2           22          5
2           22          5
2           22          2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But its not working in Teradata. recursive call can not implemented in Teradata.

Comment: find some alternate to implement the `recursive` call in teradata. there must be some way to implement it. or create a fiddle if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got the same result by adding recursive keyword just before ct and done few other syntax changes. Can you explain how the recursive call is working ? What is the purpose of having sl ?

Comment: please update your code by editing this ans, so that it helps the people who made search for `teradata`.

Comment: The differences are: Standard SQL requires `with RECURSIVE` and *Modulo* is calculated in Teradata using `a mod 5`. I added an answer showing a simplified recursive query

Answer (score 1):

DarkRob's recursive query can be simplified to

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 (
   SELECT id
      -- remainder or 5 if no remainder
     ,CASE WHEN Cnt MOD 5 = 0 THEN 5 ELSE Cnt MOD 5 END AS val
      -- how many rows left?
     ,(Cnt - val) / 5 AS x
   FROM tab
   WHERE Cnt > 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT id, 5, x -  1
   FROM cte
   WHERE x > 0
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

But I would prefer (ab)using Teradata's *Time Series Expansion* feature:

```
SELECT tab.*,
   End(pd) - Begin(pd) AS val
FROM tab
WHERE Cnt > 0
-- create one rows for each group of 5 (days)
EXPAND ON PERIOD(DATE, DATE + Cnt) AS pd BY INTERVAL '5' DAY
```